# How to set cookies client-side from a server on different domain (express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, cross-domain

My client-side application is hosted on domain foo.com and server is on domain bar.com. I'm trying to set cookie with following flags: httponly, secure, sameSite: none. It works on chrome but not on other browsers.

Question is how do I set such a cookie? According to my reading sameSite:none and secure should allow this but it doesn't work.

Domains and server setups are fixed and cannot be changed, so front-end will remain on foo.com and back-end on bar.com.

Specifically back-end is express.js and following snippet works on chrome:

```
            res
                .cookie("FOO", "BAR", {
                  path: "/",
                  domain: "",
                  maxAge: maxAgeVariable,
                  httpOnly: true,
                  secure: true,
                  sameSite: "None"
                })
```

however it doesnt work anywhere else like firefox.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello mate, did you get it to work?

Comment: I was having the same issue. Copied your cookie settings and everything works for me. Even on different browsers.